# Replace malloc / free in this code

Tags: c

The code below is storing a pointer of `tmpbuffer`.  How would I store the `tmpbuffer` itself and not a pointer in an array like `fwBuffer` and not use `malloc` / `free`?

```
short int *fwBuffer[1000000];

size =  sizeof(short int)*length*inchannels;
short int *tmpbuffer = (short int*)malloc(size);

int count = 0;
for (count = 0; count < length*inchannels; count++)
{
    tmpbuffer[count] = (short int) (inbuffer[count]);
}

fwBuffer[saveBufferCount] = tmpbuffer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to do something like this? This aggregates all the stored buffers into a single buffer. Note that I do have a separate buffer to store an index; either you may just not need this, or you could in theory pack it into a location in the fwBuffer array.

```
// Max number of data chunks
const unsigned maxBuffers = 1024;
// All the data stored here.
short int fwBuffer[1000000];
// how many data chunks we have
unsigned saveBufferCount = 0;
// Index to find each data chunk
// bufferIndex[saveBufferCount] points to where the next buffer will be placed (i.e. _after_ all the stored data).
short int* bufferIndex[maxBuffers] = {fwBuffer};

void storeBuffer(unsigned length, unsigned inchannels, short int* inbuffer)
{    
        short int *bufferIterator = bufferIndex[saveBufferCount];
        // Could do a memcpy here.
        int count = 0;
        for (count = 0; count < length*inchannels; count++)
        {
            *bufferIterator++ = inbuffer[count];
        }       
        ++saveBufferCount;
        bufferIndex[saveBufferCount] = bufferIterator;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
short int *fwBuffer[1000000];
```

is an array of `1000000` pointers of the type `short int`.
A pointer by itself is not useful unless it points to some valid memory, which belongs to a valid object in this case an object of the type `short int`.

The code allocates enough memory for a `short int`and then places that pointer in the array, thus making the array useful. It is the right way to do this because you need `1000000` items and you will probably run out of stack space if you allocate them on stack.